# Blank Page Hosting Wordpress in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

I've followed [Ry Walker's instructions in Setting up a Wordpress blog on Heroku as a subdirectory of a Rails app also hosted on Heroku.](http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku)

Everything seemed to work fine at first (I was able to access the Wordpress app through the /blog subdirectory), however after a few minutes I started getting a blank page as result of both /blog and [blog-app].herokuapp.com

I have gone through the steps twice and the same problem persists. Unfortunately, Heroku logs does not show any errors. I am afraid that this is related to the `RewriteBase` directive.

Has anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: Usually the "white screen of death" is caused by whitespace in a .php file outside of the `<?php .. ?>` block. There are other causes too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770450/reverse-proxy-with-heroku-for-wordpress-wont-show-full-pages/24813254#24813254), and it ended up being related to a bug in the `rack-reverse-proxy` gem where the content length header was getting corrupted.

There have been two people that have offered up fixes to the gem, but the fixes haven't been merged into the master branch.  I forked the branch, [copied the fix somebody had suggested](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy/pull/39/files), and used my version of the gem in the Gemfile.  It's been working great ever since.

Here's the change you'll need to make in lib/rack/reverse-proxy.rb

```
# ensure content length header is correct
res.content_length = body.bytesize
```